# Calling server side methods using ajax inside a custom extension

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I am creating a custom extension for DNN using [Christoc's DotNetNuke Module and Theme Development Template](https://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/)

I want to call server side methods using ajax inside my javascript file

*example code*

```
$.ajax({
  url:'myModule/listOfPosts'
  success:function() {
    // do something with list of posts    
  }
});
```

How can i do this? I am open to all suggestions. Thank You

Comment: Suggestion: Read this: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/142400/getting-started-with-services-framework-webapi-edition

Answer (score 0):

I did a tutorial on exactly this topic.  Building DNN framework services for your module and then calling them securely using jquery ajax.

[Client-centric module development](http://www.dnnhero.com/Premium/Tutorial/ArticleID/246/Client-Centric-Module-Development-in-DNN-Introduction-Explanation-Part-1-4)

Also, I have another example on my website:

[Rich-client Module with Knockout](http://www.dotnetnuclear.com/articles/tabid/88/ID/10/Advanced-DotNetNuke-Rich-Client-Modules--Knockoutjs-jQuery-and-Services-Framework.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using AjaxPro.dll. 
Here is the codeplex URL: [AjaxPro 2](https://ajaxpro.codeplex.com/)

**Design Section:**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" onclick="javascript:deleteRecord();" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function deleteRecord() {
    Modules.MyAdmin.ViewCars.deleteCar();  // asynchronous call        
}
```

**Code Behind:**

```
namespace Modules.MyAdmin 
{
    public partial class ViewCars : PortalModuleBase
    {   
          [AjaxPro.AjaxMethod]
          public void deleteCar()
          {    
              // Write your action over here  
          }
    }
 }
```